# Matlab - Plotting Graph Vertex and Edges

Tags: matlab, plot

Basically, I'm starting to learn graph theory and I want to plot an undirected graph and cannot find anywhere that specifically has an implementation for this in Matlab. I have the following matrix:

```
G = [0, 0, 1; 0, 0, 1; 1, 1, 0];
```

How would I therefore plot this, to get the result of below?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could try [wgPlot](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24035-wgplot-weighted-graph-plot-a-better-version-of-gplot) or [gplotwl](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/1044-gplotwl).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`gplot`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gplot.html) where you specify only the Adjacency Matrix and the Coordinates of the Nodes.

```
G = [0, 0, 1; 0, 0, 1; 1, 1, 0];
xy = [1 1; 0 0 ; 2 0];
gplot(G,xy,'-o');
axis([-1 3 -1 3]) % To Centre the Figure
```

If you want to make it look fancier, you can play with the Thickness and stuff as:

```
hline = findobj(gcf, 'type', 'line');
set(hline,'LineWidth',3)
```

Which gives:

[image]
Note: The figure you have pasted as sample doesn't correspond to the Matrix you have provided.

Comment: So does the `xy` plot the position on the graph?